# Moodle integration with angular application

Tags: java, angular, moodle, moodle-api, lti

I am new to moodle ,just started now. i am trying to integrate moodle with my application (angular 4) . my basic idea is to use moodel as content source and i have separate application through user can launch the course . and i have to get the response from moodle web service (course progress) .

i just stated the documentation .using LTI  i done some poc to launch the course externally(silent url).but unfortunately it logging the moodle application too. i don't want to login moodle application . i just want to launch course from my another app .

Please share your thoughts for above approach

Comment: So You want your application to be the tool consumer and you want Moodle to be the Tool Provider? https://www.imsglobal.org/specs/ltiv1p1p1/implementation-guide. If that's the case, checkout these docs. https://docs.moodle.org/35/en/LTI_and_Moodle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old question, not sure if this still matters, but If your courses are set to public, you can load the course using an i-frame within your application. Depending on the plugins/modules used in the course, not everything might work though. Some blocks/mods are contextual and specific to users logged in.

Option 2 is to use web services and make calls to pull data and build the parts you need from the course in your application.

Option 3 you can create a moodle user on the fly using web services and then automatically log them from your application (maybe embed the course using an iframe). I built a local plugin that lets you pass in a web service token and URL to redirect to once logged in. example: my-moodle-site.com/local/token_auth/redirect.php?token=REPLACE_ME_WITH_TOKEN&url=REPLACE_ME_WITH_URL

Example: http://moodle35.dev/local/token_auth/redirect.php?token=8sdf9sdj33&url=/calendar/export.php